# Error in operating on big database

Tags: c++, ms-access, exception, database-connection

I am trying to delete rows of table by ID in `.mdb` file, however an exception appears when working with big `.mdb` files (with size 35 MB or more). Exception is "`System resources exceeded (3035)`".

But when working with small files there is no problem.

The connection is implemented by using CDaoDatabse, which represents a connection to a database through which you can operate on the data. And program is written in C++.

Piece of code is shown below:

```
CDaoDatabase* pDatabase
BeginTransaction(pDatabase);

  try
    {
    sSQL.Format("Delete from %s where %s = %d",DaoTrianglesTable,DaoObjectIdField,nObjectId);
    pDatabase->Execute(sSQL);
    }
  catch(CDaoException* e)
    {        
    DisplayDaoException(e);
    EndTransaction(pDatabase,false);      
    }  
EndTransaction(pDatabase,true);
```

Note that, if I delete functions `BeginTransaction()` and `EndTransaction()` and run program then no problem. However, I am not sure that it is right solution, is there any alternative solution of problem? May be someone encountered such kind of case?

Answer (score 1):

First, 35MB for an Access database is really not big, it's kind of small actually.

However, when doing transactions, Access keeps track of all deleted data and if you are deleting a lot, you may exceed the number of locks that Access uses during the transaction.

Have a look at the following:

- [File sharing lock count exceeded…" error message during large transaction processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815281)
- [Optimizing Your Microsoft Access Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188207%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Another issue that can arise if you are doing a lot of looping that connects/disconnects to the Access database is that the lock file may not be released quickly enough before you attempt to connect to the database again.
In that case, just make sure you keep a connection to the database, and keep it open until you're completely done.

Instead of using transactions, you could also add the `dbFailOnError` to `Execute()`.
Another way would also be to do away with the transactions completely by first making a copy of the database as a backup, doing the deletes, and manually restoring the database if there is a big issue.

In most cases though, I've never seen the database fail during a `DELETE` operation, unless relationships between tables have complex cascading update/deletes that can create failures in other constraints.

Comment: Your first variant was right. We tried to run SQL query directly inside Access and got following message "There is not enough memory to undo this transaction, do you still want to proceed with this query?”"  This explains why removing begin/end transaction calls solves problem

Answer (score 1):

Hotfix for Access 2010: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2726928
"System Resource Exceeded" error message when you perform a query in Access 2010"

Dated October 30, 2012. Your mileage may vary.